# Java JDK isn't recognized by VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I installed Java via `apt.get install default-jdk` and verified the installation via `java -version`, I am using `openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14`

But VS code still still gives me an error message
`Java 8 or more recent it`

[Here you can see what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om2OA.png)

Comment: how is your java.home preference in vscode settings?

Comment: No, where can I find  the path? (I am from Windows and installed ubuntu today)

Comment: Just open up vscode and then click on code-> preferences -> settings > click on Java from the left side -> Home

Comment: I set it to `"java.home": "/etc/java-11-openjdk"` , but VS says it does not point to a jdk,  where would it normaly be installed?

Comment: nope you add the bin path of Java

Comment: just run this command to find the bin path from terminal `readlink -f $(which java)`. Once you get the bin path then add it `"java.home":"java/bin/path/here"`. note that no spaces between `:`

Comment: Wow, thanks guys, you're awesome, but now it says: `The java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java) does not point to a JDK.`

Comment: have you written it correctly?

Comment: I copied and pasted it

Comment: copy paste until bin

Comment: Oh, wow, should have thought about that XD

Comment: Thanks, you guys are awesome!

Comment: does it work now? do not forget to restart vscode?

Comment: Shall I add that as answer so that other people can be benefited from it?

Answer (score 3):

Check java version:

```
java -version
```

Find the java bin path using the command

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

Check the `java.home` preference in vscode settings. You find it by navigating to `Code -> Preferences -> Settings > Click on Java from the left side -> Home`

Set `java.home`:

```
"java.home":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

Save and restart vscode.

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA and VSCode on my machine. I had installed both openJDK from apt and IntelliJ IDEA had also installed OracleJDK under jvm. I wanted to use OracleJDK instead of OpenJDK in VSCode by default. This answer helped me. Only difference is I needed to remove "bin" from the path for java.home. So in my case it was "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.2/". Thanks for your help.